# get specific subarray of a bigger array in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

lets say we got an array and we want to get the 2-5 elements of it, is there a way we can do that like in python?

```
let test = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];
```

in python we can do,

```
test[1:4]
```

and this will return us the 2nd to 5th elements does node offer a simple way to do this that way?

Comment: There is [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `slice` method:

```
let test = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];
test.slice(1,4) // ['b', 'c', 'd' ]
```